# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command, without nested datareaders

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, database-connection

I'm getting the following error intermittently.
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

I read that this can happens when there are nested DataReaders in the same connection, but in my case, I'm using the following code to execute all queries.

```
    private SqlTransaction Transaction { get; set; }
    private SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
    private DbRow Row {get; set;}

    public Row Exec(string sql){
        try{
            //Begin connection/transaction
            Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            Connection.Open();
            Transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");  

            //create command
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, Connection);
            command.Transaction = Transaction;

            //execute reader and close it
            //HERE IS THE PROBLEM, THE READER ALWAYS READ UNTIL THE END
            //BEFORE ANOTHER CAN BE OPENED
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();                
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                object[] value = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                reader.GetValues(value);
                List<object> values = new List<object>(value);                    
                Rows.Add(values);
            }                
            reader.Close();
            Transaction.Commit();
            Connection.Dispose();
            Connection = null;
        }
        catch
        {
           Transaction.Rollback();
           Connection.Dispose();
           Connection = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null && !reader.IsClosed) reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

This way, The result is stored in an object and there isn't nested readers.
I also read that adding 'MultipleActiveResultSets=True' to connection string can solve the problem when using nested readers.
Does this solution also solve my problem?
As the error is intermitent and only happens in production environment, I can't test it many times.

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. at 
          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command) at 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Rollback() at

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Rollback() at 

Application.Lib.DB.DBSQLServer.Rollback()
 at Application.Lib.DB.DBSQLServer.Execute(String sql, Dictionary`2 parameters, 

Nullable`1 timeout, Boolean useTransaction) at 

Application.UtilDB.Execute(String sql, Dictionary`2 parameters, Nullable`1 

timeout, Boolean useTransaction) in c:\Application\DBUtil.cs:line 37 at 

Application.A.CollectionFromDataBase(Int32 cenId, 

IDB db, Int32 includeId, Boolean allStatus) in c:\Application\Activities.cs:line 64 at

Application.ActivitiesController.CheckForConflictsBeforeSave(String aulId, String insId) in c:\Application\AlocController.cs:line 212
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for this entire method?

Comment: @BryanCrosby I have just edit the question, this is not the full code, but is the part that matters.

Comment: Can you also please post the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Just found it, thank you @BryanCrosby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that, when a query fails, the transaction can't be rolled back because the data reader is already open to process the query.

A second exception is thrown and the first one is lost.

I just placed the rollback inside a try catch block and used the AggregateException class to throw both exceptions.

```
try
{
    Transaction.Rollback();
    Connection.Dispose();
    Connection = null;
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{                                                      
    throw new AggregateException(new List<Exception>() { e, ex2 });
}
```

Although the transaction will be rolled back anyway, I think you can also try to close the data reader before the rollback, so it will probably work.

```
if (reader != null && !reader.IsClosed) 
    reader.Close();
Transaction.Rollback();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this happens only on production it's more likely that bug is outside the code you attached.

Most common way to prevent this is to always code in following fashion:

```
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
try
{
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            dbResult.Columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
            dbResult.Types.Add(reader.GetDataTypeName(i));
        }
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            object[] value = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            reader.GetValues(value);
            List<object> values = new List<object>(value);                    
            Rows.Add(values);
        }                            
}
finally
{
    reader.Close();
}
```

Notice the `finally` block, it makes sure reader is closed no matter what. I am under impression that something happens in your code that leaves the reader open but the bug isn't visible in the code you've posted.

I recommend you enclose it in the above try/finally block <s>and your bug is quite likely to be resolved</s>.

Edit, to clarify: This may not resolve whatever bug exists outside the scope of the originally shown code but it will prevent data readers being left open. The `finally` block I suggested won't block any exceptions, they will be propagated to whatever handler you employ outside of it.

Comment: Of course knowing that a bug exists and leaving it around without fixing is not really a solution.

Comment: As I suggested, your bug appears to be **outside of the source code visible to us**. For example, we can't see where is the `command` or `reader` declared and how it's used outside the scope of the code you have shown us.

Comment: Please try to understand my point. Adding the finally clause will fix the problem with the reader. It _will close the reader no matter what_ as you say. And this is what I find not acceptable in your answer. If the poster follows your advice to blindly add the finally clause he/she will forget that there is a problem and probably will deploy a bugged code that will raise its head again in any moment. At this point better add a catch and log the exception somewhere or just display it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, But Actually, I'm doing it. I just edited the question.

Comment: @Steve I see your point, I rectified the answer to hopefully at least make it clearer.